# Max requests in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Does anyone know if there is a maximum number of concurrent requests for IIS (Specifically IIS 7), I understand that there is a maximum number of threads so this will limit the max number of concurrent requests. Is this true?

Comment: This probably belongs on ServerFault (even though I managed to miss click and select SuperUser - Doh!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS 7.0 you can limit your web site usage by setting the following values:

```
Bandwith usage (maxBandwidth)
Connection (maxConnections)
Connection time-out (connectionTimeout)
```

The connection limit specifies the maximim number of permitted connections for a particular website. By limiting connections to Web sites, you can effectively allocate system resources.You can set all three limits from a single dialog box in IIS manager(inetmgr). **Connection limit can range from 0 to 4294967295**.

Comment: Where is this setting in IIS?